# boost::phoenix error message while used as a functor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I am trying to learn boost::phoenix and trying to use it in std::transform like below.

```
class myClass
{
   int i;

public:
   getNumber(); 
   setNumber(int j); 
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<myClass*> vect
   std::vector<int> numVect

   numVect.resize(vect.size());
   using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
   std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), arg1->getNumber());
}
```

But, I am getting an error `error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::argument<0> >'`

I am not really sure what does it mean. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you give up.  Don't take this the wrong way--I just think Phoenix is too complicated to use for real, and you've found a great example of why--most C++ users will never be able to help you fix this, much less figure out how to modify it later on.  Just use a normal for loop or something.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. But, I think I just found out the correct way to do it                                                       std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::back_insterter(numVect), (arg1->*&getNumber)());

Comment: Great.  Now forget you ever knew that, and future maintainers of your code will like you more.  :)  Anyway, feel free to post your own answer if you get a fully working version coded up using the same names as in your question.

Comment: Oh well. I personally think Phoenix has lot's of things going for it. At least until we can have polymorphic lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

As you note above, the way to do this with Phoenix is with `phoenix::bind` or with `->*` as you do above:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/phoenix/core.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/transform.hpp>

class myClass
{
    int i;

public:
    int getNumber() { return i; }
    void setNumber(int j) { i = j; }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<myClass*> vect;
   std::vector<int> numVect;

   using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
   boost::transform(vect,
                    std::back_inserter(numVect),
                    (arg1->*&myClass::getNumber)());
}
```

Phoenix can be complicated, and bind expressions are some of the most convoluted and contrived of Phoenix's syntactic contortions, but in all honestly, this one doesn't seem that bad.

C++14's polymorphic lambdas will obviate much of Phoenix, by the way.

Comment: +1 This is a nice display of the 'puritan' way (including `back_inserter` :)). However, I'd always prefer `bind` or `function<>` of some kind (I show using `phoenix::lambda` in my answer)

Comment: PS. The real puritan way would, of course, be `std::mem_fn(&myClass::getNumber)`... but that wouldn't do justice to the tags

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), phx::bind(&myClass::getNumber, arg1));
```

Or, if you wanted nicer syntax:

```
auto getNumber = phx::lambda [ phx::bind(&myClass::getNumber, arg1) ];
std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), getNumber(arg1));
```

Demo:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct myClass
{
   int i;

   int getNumber() const { return i; }
   void setNumber(int j) { i = j; }
};

using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;
static const auto getNumber = phx::lambda [ phx::bind(&myClass::getNumber, arg1) ];

int main()
{
   const std::vector<myClass*> vect { new myClass{1}, new myClass{2}, new myClass{42} };
   std::vector<int> numVect(vect.size());

   // puritan/standard version:
   std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), std::mem_fn(&myClass::getNumber));

   // just bind:
   std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), phx::bind(&myClass::getNumber, arg1));

   // using more natural syntax
   std::transform (vect.begin(), vect.end(), numVect.begin(), getNumber(arg1));

   for(auto i : numVect)
       std::cout << i << " ";
}
```